# Producer-Consumer: Buffer to receive n consecutive messages from same Producer

Tags: java, multithreading, producer-consumer

So, my producers send n consecutive messages to the buffer and then an end message (note that I cannot modify Producer.java and this code portion isn't synchronized):

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    buffer.send(message[i]);
buffer.send(endMessage);
```

The message doesn't contain the thread's id or something that could lead from which thread is the message from.

The buffer needs to receive those n messages(+end message) in consecutive order and I cannot have a message from another thread in between them.
Good Example:

```
received Msg1 from Thread1
           received Msg2 from Thread1
           etc.
           received MsgN from Thread1
           received end  from Thread1

           received Msg1 from Thread2 
           received Msg2 from Thread2
           etc.
           received MsgN from Thread2
           received end  from Thread2
```

Bad Example:

```
 received Msg1 from Thread1
               received Msg2 from Thread1
               etc. 
               received Msg6 from Thread1

               received Msg1 from Thread2
               received Msg2 from Thread2

               received Msg7 from Thread1
               etc.
```

How could I synchronize my code in Buffer.java to get the messages in order? I clearly need to make use of the end message to allow other threads after the thread's finished sending but from here on it's all question marks.

Comment: i think you can put your messages in, like, `LinkedHashMap` so it will guarantee you the order. Regarding to the threads, you can implement some `wait()` / `notify()` logic, like when you get `end` message, `notify()` other threads

Comment: i can't write in the thread's class. that's the thing. i'm only allowed to modify the buffer's class.